# More elegant way to loop through a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

For one iterable, we can loop through using

```
for item in items:
```

But what if I have two iterables side by side, think about a pandas dataframe with 2 columns for example. I can use the above approach to loop through one column, but is there a more elegant way to loop through both columns at the same time?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col 1': [1,2,3,4,5], 'col 2': [6,7,8,9,10]})
i = 0
for j in df['col 1']:
    print(j)
    print(df['col 2'][i])
    i += 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: `zip(df['col 1']), df['col 2'])`?

Comment: This is an XY problem. Rather than asking "how do I do implement this potentially poor solution for some problem I'm not going to tell you about", you should ask "what is the best way to solve my problem"?

Comment: In general, iterating through a Pandas dataframe should be your *last* option. See [this article](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) for some details, but if you find yourself looping over a dataframe, **stop** and see if you can vectorize!

Comment: To get better answers, I recommend changing the subject of the question to something that indicates that you want a nested iteration, not just "looping" which generally indicates a simple 1 dimensional iteration.

Answer (score 3):

You've already gotten some great answers to your question. However, I would also like to provide you with a different approach altogether which could be even more elegant (depending on what your end goal is).

As a general rule of thumb, you want to avoid looping through the rows of a dataframe. That tends to be slow and there's usually a better way. Try to shift your thinking into applying a function to entire "vector" (fancy word for dataframe column).

Check this out:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col 1': [1,2,3,4,5], 'col 2': [6,7,8,9,10]})

def sum_2_cols(col1,col2):
    return col1 + col2

df['new_col'] = np.vectorize(sum_2_cols)(df['col 1'], df['col 2'])
```

The `np.vectorize` method is very powerful, flexible, and fast. It allows you to apply your own functions to a dataframe and it tends to perform very well. Try it out, you might get inspired to go about solving your problem in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

the `zip` built-in function creates iterables that aggregates whatever you pass as parameters, so this should be an alternative:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col 1': [1,2,3,4,5], 'col 2': [6,7,8,9,10]})
for i,j in zip(df['col 1'], df['col 2']):
    print(i)
    print(j)
```

Output:

```
1
6
2
7
3
8
4
9
5
10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through entire rows which is more elegant:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['col 1'], row['col 2'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [DataFrame.itertuples()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) method to loop through both columns at the same time:

```
for i, j in df[['col 1', 'col 2']].itertuples(index=False):
    print(i)
    print(j)
```